# Meeting permission error on my Firestore rule accessing other user's path

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm testing permission for accessing user A's document from login user B.
User B already saved uid_A on it's path /userData/uid_B/subscriber/uid_A.
In this situation, I'd like to access A's document by checking subscriber in Firestore rule.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  ..
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /userData/{uid}/{document=**} {
      allow create, read, update, delete: if exists(/databases/{database}/documents/userData/$(request.auth.uid)/subscriber/$(uid));
    }
  }
}
```

But following Flutter code fails with this message:

6.33.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Listen for query at userData/uid_A failed: Missing or insufficient permissions.

```dart
await db.collection('userData').doc('uid_A').get();
```

The reason user B want's to access user A's document is to add uid_B as user A's provider, so user A can easily list up his accessible documents on screen.

I wonder what's causing this issue and how to resolve this kind of problem.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: The path used in exists had syntax error, I've replaced {database} to $(database) and all worked nice. Thank you Doug Stevenson!

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for the document to check with `exists()` isn't correct.  The full path includes more, as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents):

```
  exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/userData/$(request.auth.uid)/subscriber/$(uid));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I got same result after replacing it with full path. I wonder there's more structural problem with my rule.

Comment: OMG the path /databases/{database}/documents was wrong, I was tried this path all days! You saved my life thanks!!